# Limit RequiredFieldValidator to validate when a certain button is clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am working on a web application and I have a problem with RequiredFieldValidator.

I have a button "Insert Movie", and a div that contains other two buttons(save movie and cancel), one TextBox for Title, one TextBox for Description and a RequiredFieldValidator for Title.
This div is not displayed by default.
Here is my problem:
When I click insert, on the client side I use javascript to hide the insert button and show my div.
Clicking the button I make a PostBack and my div is showed with the RequiredFieldValidator error message to.
I don't want this behavior.I want to show the validation error just after the save button is clicked.
Here is my code...

```
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Validation Test</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= TitleValidator.ClientID%>'), false);
        });
        function ShowInsertForm() {
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= TitleValidator.ClientID%>'), true);
            $('#InsertForm').show();
        }
        function HideInsertForm() {
            $('#InsertForm').hide();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Insert" runat="server" Text="Insert Movie" OnClientClick="ShowInsertForm();"/>
    </div>
    <div id="InsertForm" style="display:none">
        <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save Movie" onclick="Save_Click" OnClientClick="HideInsertForm();"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel Movie" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="HideInsertForm();"/>
        <br />
        Title<asp:TextBox ID="Title" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TitleValidator" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Please insert Title" ControlToValidate="Title"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        Description<asp:TextBox ID="Description" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1- as you are using Insert button just for client slide functionality , I suggest replacing `<asp:button>` control with a `html button tag` . this way it no more fires validations .

2- and if you have to use `asp:button` you can set its `causeValidation` to `false` . and even better you can prevent it from causing a `post-back` by editing `ShowInsertForm` function

```
    function ShowInsertForm() {
        ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= TitleValidator.ClientID%>'), true);
        $('#InsertForm').show();
        return false;
    }
```